# How to connect to MongoDB on mLab through mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, shell

I'm trying to connect to my database cluster on mLab through `mongo` shell using the commands as mentioned by the service providers but I keep getting the same error mentioning missing ";" statement. I can access the same database through mongoose client without any problem.

Any clue where I am messing up:

```
mongo ds117956.mlab.com:17956/image_search -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>

2017-11-29T03:04:33.139+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:6
```

Comment: You asked this question a while ago, but based on the error message it looks like you were trying to run your command in the `mongo` shell rather than a command-line shell (such as `bash` on Linux or `cmd.exe` on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

you need to run from  **mongodb/bin** 
and then enter the following command: mongo ds117956.mlab.com:17956/image_search -u  -p

not from mongo itself

> mongo ds117956.mlab.com:17956/image_search -u  -p